# How to make changes to a single user's google calendar using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

I'm designing a google apps script that is linked to a bot that needs to add and delete events to a specific user's calendar. I need to find a way to do this without giving edit access to all people with access to the script. I was thinking of using the calendar api but that uses oauth2.0. Is there a way to use an api key instead? Another option I was considering was using a service account with domain-wide delagation, but I don't if it's possible to do what I want with it. Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little advanced, but fesable.

You need to use the Calendar API with a service account and domain-wide delegation and OAuth2. I have described the process [in this story on Medium](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-use-service-accounts-and-oauth2-in-google-apps-script-99c4bc91dc31?source=friends_link&sk=91695899162e741ff54bec4d60b6ea7b) (make sure to read through all three examples), however the steps are pretty much as follows:

1. Create a service account
2. Download its JSON key
3. Enable domain-wide delegation
4. Impersonate a super-user
5. Create token with OAuth2
6. Send request to the Calendar API with `Bearer` token generated with OAuth2