# How to extract all domain users calendar events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

We have G-suite business in our company and I was asked to create a script that extracts all calendar events from all the users in the company domain for future processing. The goal here is to create some useful KPIs for meeting times.

I know that I should use the Calendar API. In fact, I've already done that, but I think I'm missing something.

Should I run the script with an admin account?
Should all user's calendars be shared with the user that runs the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a service account with domain-wide delegation of authority you will not have to ask your domain users to share the calendars, but if your domain have just a few of users that might work too.

Related

- [Get All Google Calendars Shared Within A Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19731102/1595451)
- [Get a list of all coworkers' calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37741631/1595451)
- [can I set/change the owner Google Calendar event using an Apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64988819/1595451)
- [How to make changes to a single user's google calendar using google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69555277/1595451)

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation